# HorizontalPodAutoscaler - Scale Deployment in Another Namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I'm attempting to get autoscaling set up using custom metrics.

Currently, I have:

- [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator) running in the `monitoring` namespace.
- [K8S Prometheus Adapter](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) running in the `custom-metrics` namespace, exposed through a service named `api`.
- A deployment running in the `my-namespace` namespace.

I added a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` in the `custom-metrics` namespace, targeting my deployment.

The YAML looks like:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-hpa
  namespace: custom-metrics
spec:
  maxReplicas: 10
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      metricName: queue_length
      targetValue: 1000
      target:
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Service
        name: api
```

When I describe the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` via `kubectl describe hpa my-deployment-hpa -n custom-metrics`, I see `AbleToScale: False` because `FailedGetScale the HPA controller was unable to get the target's current scale: deployments/scale.extensions "my-deployment" not found`.

Does Kubernetes expect that the custom metrics API, the scale target and the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` all exist in the same namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Deployment` which you want to scale should be in the same namespace with `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object.

Here is an extract from the Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/):

> Namespaces provide a scope for names. Names of resources need to be
>   unique within a namespace, but not across namespaces.

The `Namespace` value of the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object is the only way to provide information about namespace of deployment which you want to scale.

Comment: Enhanced version of this question: Does the adapter have to be in the same namespace as well?